# Transfer the context of `this.data` to other templates in Blaze/Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a route gathering some data.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('Players.guild', {
    path: '/players/guild/:guildId',
    template: 'GuildPlayerList',
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('guild_players', this.params.guildId);
    },
    data: function () {
      return Players.find({ guildId: this.params.guildId });
    }
  });
});
```

Then, I have a simple template

```
template(name="GuildPlayerList")
  +ionList
    +each this
      +ionItem avatar=true ion-data-modal="_playerModalView"
        img(src="{{ imageId store='PlayerThumbnails' }}" alt="{{ name }}")
        h2 {{ name }}

template(name="_playerModalView")
  // I want the current player in the +each to push its context of this here
  +ionModal title="{{ name }}"
```

The problem, however, is it seems that the context of `this` changes when I load the modal. In other cases, I have used `_.bind` to push the context of `this`, but how can this be done with blaze templates?

Comment: what is that syntax you are using in the templates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully follow your syntax and you don't explain what the `ion` things are, but in regular html syntax you can simply provide a data argument to the dynamically included template, as described in 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic, so in your case (but html syntax):

```
{{> _playerModalView data=this}}
```